# If $M$ has hyper-kaehler structure then $M//G$ has hyper-kaehler structure?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry

> A) Let $M$ is a non-compact manifold and $G$ be a compact Lie group which
>   acts on $M$ and preserves complex structure then If $M$ has Kaehler
>   manifold, then the symplectic quotient of $M$, i.e, $M//G$ has kaehler
>   structure?

What about hyper-kaehler?

> B) If $M$ has hyper-kaehler structure then $M//G$ has hyper-kaehler
>   structure?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $(X,\omega)=(M,I,\omega)$ is Kaehler, and $G$ is a compact Lie group, which acts freely on $M$ and preserves *both* $I$ and $\omega$, then the symplectic quotient *is* Kaehler. More precisely, $M//G\simeq X^{st}/G^c$, where $G^c$ is the complexification of $G$, and $X^{st}\subset X$ are the stable points for the action. See, e.g., [HKLR, Theorem 3.1](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1104116624) 
and Hitchin's [Sem. Bourbaki 748](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/SB/SB_1991-1992__34_/SB_1991-1992__34__137_0/SB_1991-1992__34__137_0.pdf), section 3.4.

In the hyperkaehler case, there is again compatibility with the symplectic quotient, but it is more subtle. Your suggestion in B) cannot possibly work, because
$\dim_R M-2\dim_R G$ need not be divisible by $4$. The actual relation is as follows. Suppose $M$ is hyperkaehler, and $G$ (acts freely in a hamiltonian way by isometries and) preserves "the" three Kaehler forms $\omega_I$, $\omega_J$, $\omega_K$. Then
we have a moment map
$$
\mu=(\mu_I,\mu_J,\mu_K): M\to \mathbb{R}^3\otimes\mathfrak{g}^\vee,
$$
and for a regular value $\xi$, the quotient $\mu^{-1}(\xi)/G$ is hyperkaehler (see HKLR, Theorem 3.2 and SB 748, Theorem 3.) **added:** provided $\xi$ is $G$-invariant.

If you want to link this with the symplectic or Kaehler quotient, you  fix one of the complex structures, say $I$, and break the three moment maps into a real moment map $\mu_I$ and a complex one, $\mu_c=\mu_J+i\mu_K$. Then, if
$\xi=(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3)$, we have
$$
\mu^{-1}(\xi) = \mu_I^{-1}(\xi_1)\bigcap\mu_c^{-1}(z)
$$
where $z=\xi_2+i\xi_3$.
The hyperkaehler quotient is the symplectic reduction of $\mu_c^{-1}(z)$,  or equivalently, the Kaehler quotient
$\mu_c^{-1}(z)^{st}/G^c$.

Comment: But for the action of $S^1$ on $\mathbb C^2$,  the symplectic quotient is $\mathbb P^1$, which is not Kahler,so which condition here does not occurs?

Comment: @HassanJolany Projective spaces are all Kahler (with the Fubini-Study metric), no? I suppose that in this example it should be the same as that produced by Thm 3.1 of HKLR.

Comment: Yes, exactly, I copy/pasted Peter's comment, so by these answer $M$ is not required to be compact in general case for A)

Comment: I don't understand your comment---(1) which Peter? and (2) Neither one wrote exactly what you did, as far as I can tell. It seems to me that Peter Crooks is incorrect in asserting that his response addresses your A) above.

Comment: Peter Crooks made small mistake in A). I wanted just say A) as you see I gave a reference to his comment

Comment: Hassan, I never made the comment you have written. I claimed that $\mathbb{P}^1$ was not hyper-Kahler. It is obviously Kahler. I must have misinterpreted your part A). To me, it sounded like you were claiming the quotient was Kahler, and wanted to understand whether $M$ being Kahler was enough to ensure the quotient was hyper-Kahler.

Comment: I have seen this Kahler quotient called $M //// G$, in keeping with the idea that in $M//G$ we subtract $G$ off twice.

Comment: Theorem 3.2 in HKLR only talks about reduction at 0.  Reduction away from zero is a bit more delicate.  In particular I don't think your answer is literally correct unless $\xi$ is 0

Comment: @Eugene Lerman: Well, that's why I have the condition that $\xi$ should be a <i>regular</i> value (and hence the level set of the moment map is a manifold). Look also at Theorem 3 in Hitchin's Bourbaki talk, linked above.

Comment: @Peter Dalakov My point is that unless the stabilizer of $\xi$ is all of $G$, there is not reason for $\mu^{-1} (\xi)$ to be $G$-invariant.  In symplectic setting this can be taken care of by the shifting trick.  But in general the coadjoint orbits of compact Lie groups are only Kaehler, not hyperKaheler.  So the shifting trick in the hyperKaehler setting does not work.

Comment: @Eugene: Of course you're right, sorry -  I was assuming $\xi$ to $G$-invariant. Thanks, my bad.

Answer (score 5):

No, I think this need not be the case. Consider the usual action of $S^1$ on $\mathbb{C}^2$. The symplectic quotient is $\mathbb{P}^1$, which is not hyper-Kahler for dimension reasons.

Comment: thanks PETER, So, I understand why Hitchin introduced another definition for symplectic quotient of hyper-kahler manifolds

Comment: But what about A) is it correct?, I know that when $M$ is compact then the reduced space certainly has kahler structure

Comment: But here in Theorem 3.3, he didn't mention that $M$ must be compact, I doubted and asked this question http://math.berkeley.edu/~alanw/277papers00/zhu.pdf

Comment: Okay, I apparently misinterpreted your question in part A). It did not sound like you were asking a question about the Kahler structure.

Comment: Peter Crooks, I am sorry, My question had not been written very well.

Answer (score 3):

There is a notion called hyperkahler quotient, if it is what you ask. (cf. Hitchin, etc., Hyperkahler Metrics and Supersymmetry, Commun. Math. Phys. 108, 535-589 (1987)).  Assume that G is a compact Lie group acting freely on a hyperkahler manifold M, which preserves the complex structures I, J, K, and corresponding Kahler forms $\omega_{I}$,   $\omega_{J}$ and $\omega_{K}$.  If we have three moment maps $h_{I}$ $h_{J}$  $h_{K}$, then we denote $$h=(h_{I},h_{J},h_{K}): M \rightarrow g^{*} \otimes R^{3},$$ and $h^{-1}(0)/G$ is a hyperkahlerian. See Theorem 3.2 in the above paper.

Comment: yes http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperk%C3%A4hler_quotient, but, I am looking for noramal definition of symplectic quotient introduced by Marsdern and not this definition you mentioned. Your moment map is different. If you see I have used of $M//G$ and not $M///G$ which is for notation of Hitchin's reduced space for Hyperkahler manifolds